# HTML error when Passing data from Parent component to Child Component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In here i am passing data from parent to child and trying to draw a graph by using those data. This is my graph drawing method which is in child component `createGraph(divName, chartDataInfo)`.In here i am trying to draw 2 charts.

```
  export class ViewComponent implements OnInit{
      lineChart = ['line_chart1', 'line_chart2', 'line_chart3'];
      value = ['33.5M', '67.9M', '90.9M', '09.9M'];
      names = ['Bookings', 'Modifications','cancellations',  'Revenue' ];
      bookingInfo = [];
      mdfInfo = [];
    
      ngOnInit() {
         this.getInfo();
         this.getBookingInfo();
        }
    
      getBookingInfo() {
              const params = [];
              params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'BOOKING'});
              params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
              params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-12-31'});
    
              this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).subscribe(
                bookings => {
                  this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
                  console.log(this.bookingInfo);
              });
          }
    
       getInfo(){
        const params = [];
        params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
        params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-12-31'});
        this.ServiceHandler.getMdfInfo([], params).subscribe(
          modifications => {
            this.mdfInfo = modifications.responseObj.txnValues;
            this.modificationTtcSum = modifications.responseObj.ttcSum;
           });
      }
    
    }
```

This is my dashboard.component.html

```
<app-chips [lineChart]="lineChart[0]" [value] = "value[0]" [name] = "names[0]" [mdfInfo] = "mdfInfo"></app-summary-chips>
<app-chips [lineChart]="lineChart[1]" [value] = "value[1]" [name] = "names[1]" [bookingInfo] = "bookingInfo"></app-summary-chips>
```

This my child component. Therefore i have called `this.createGraph(this.lineChart, this.mdfInfo);` 2 times inside `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)`.But when i do like that both charts are not coming.When i call `this.createGraph(this.lineChart, this.mdfInfo)` only once inside `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` and at the same time i use only `<app-summary-chips>` selector only once then one chart is drawing. What is the reason for it?

```
export class ChipsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('lineChart') lineChart: string;
  @Input('value') value: string;
  @Input('name') name: string;
  @Input() bookingInfo = [];
  @Input()  mdfInfo = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.bookingInfo);
    console.log(this.mdfInfo );
    this.createGraph(this.lineChart, this.mdfInfo);
    this.createGraph(this.lineChart, this.bookingInfo);
    }

   createGraph(divName, chartDataInfo) {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themesAnimated);
  
    const chartNameChartTTV = am4core.create(divName, am4charts.XYChart);
    chartNameChartTTV.width = am4core.percent(100);
    chartNameChartTTV.height = am4core.percent(100);
    console.log(this.bookingInfo);
    chartNameChartTTV.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    chartNameChartTTV.data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < chartDataInfo.length; i++) {
      const booking = chartDataInfo[i];
      console.log(booking);
      chartNameChartTTV.data.push({date: booking.time, value: booking.ttc});
    }

    chartNameChartTTV.colors.list = [
      am4core.color('rgba(4, 69, 142, 1)'),
    ];

    // Create axes
    const dateAxis = chartNameChartTTV.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    const valueAxis = chartNameChartTTV.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

// Create series
    const series = chartNameChartTTV.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';
    series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
    series.tooltipText = '{value';
    series.fillOpacity = 1;
    series.strokeWidth = 2;
    series.minBulletDistance = 15;
  
  }

}
```

This is my chips.component.html

```
<div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" >
  <div class="c-summary-chip__value">{{value}}</div>
  <div class="c-summary-chip__txt">{{name}}</div>
  <div id= "{{lineChart}}" class="c-summary-chip__graph ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors on the failing scenario?

Comment: yes I am getting

Comment: in child component i am getting console.log(this.bookingInfo); console.log(this.mdfInfo ) in ngOnchanges

Comment: When i use async with ngOnChanges it prints both data bookingInfo,mdfInfo inside createGraph(divName, chartDataInfo) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code inside an if check

```
createGraph(divName, chartDataInfo) {

    if (divName && chartDataInfo.length) {}
}
```

As ngOnChanges is an async event there is no guarantee that when you call the function inside changes all parameters will be present.

Also for debugging give console.log like this.

```
createGraph(divName, chartDataInfo) {
    console.log(divName, chartDataInfo);

    if (divName && chartDataInfo) {}
}
```

That way you can confirm all required data is there when you call the function.

Comment: if (divName && chartDataInfo.length) what i want to check here

Comment: in here i want to check if (divName && chartDataInfo.length) not null

Comment: divName will be false if it's null/undefined/empty string.
chartData since its array it will be true so check for length

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ngOnChanges` hook use `SimpleChanges` to track your `input` parameters.
If params present, then call your function.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['divName'] && changes['chartDataInfo']) {
        this.createGraph(changes['divName'].currentValue, changes['chartDataInfo'].currentValue);
    }
}
```

Take a look please https://dev.to/nickraphael/ngonchanges-best-practice-always-use-simplechanges-always-1feg

Comment: But this is useful only if you are triggering based on a single input. If you use multiple inputs then there is no guarantee that at the time of ngOnChange both inputs would have currentValue. Then the code inside ngOnChanges will never execute in most of the cases.

Comment: So what’s the difference between your answer where you move checking logic into the method directly? Every time when inputs change, you will trigger createGraph and then check params. However you have SimpleChanges interface specially created for this.

Comment: You need to render chart when you have both params. So as soon as we have data, our inputs will have currentValue and after that we can trigger createGraph. Then we will be sure that the chart will be drawn with the data.

Comment: You are right ngOnChanges will trigger on each input change but what I am saying is that
changes['divName']  and changes['chartDataInfo']  will occur at different times. If you console in most cases one of the two will be undefined. So in such cases need to trigger the function but check the class member values for calculation else those fn won't get excecuted.